# Find The Least Waste When Sawing Wood Planks In A Specific Order

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming

Similar to one of the questions that was posted here roughly 4 years ago. Lets say we have two wooden planks each 1m long. And we want to have 4 pieces, 60cm 50cm 30cm and 20cm. What kind of bottom-up implementation can be done to calculate the least waste

Formally we have N wooden planks each $L_1$,…,$L_N$ cm long. And we want to have M pieces, $l_1$,$l_2$,…,$l_M$ cm long. How to minimize the waste **without changing the order the planks have been given in**?

So for example, in the example above, the optimal solution, using this new added restriction, I believe will be **[60] & [50,30,20]** instead of **[60,30] & [50,20]**

Comment: What progress have you made?  Please study https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info and try to follow the systematic approach listed there, and show what you've come up with and where you got stuck.

Comment: What exactly does `without changing the order the planks have been given in` mean? *You take the first plank, saw off the first few millimetres just to be sure, saw off 60cm and 30cm and find the rest to be shorter than 10 cm (even 9: each cut wastes at least the width of the blade). You start another plank…*? I don't see how processing either the planks or the pieces in specified order changes anything. Or how processing *both* in specified order left any choice.

Comment: (`the questions that was posted here roughly 4 years ago` there is quite a number of questions, better hyperlink [What algorithm to use, least waste when sawing wood planks](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/79430).)

Comment: @greybeard In the order the planks have been given in means that I have to first saw 60 cm, then saw 50 cm, then saw 30 cm and then 20. But I also have to keep in mind that I have to minimize the waste as much as possible. So a greedy algorithm implementation will not always work. A dynamic programming approach will be the best way to do so. But I have no clue how to come up with the bottom up implementation

Comment: *60, 50, 30, 20* is the order the *pieces* have been specified in - $L_1 = L_2 =$ 100 cm. Try to find an example where the order of pieces matters *while free to start sawing another plank and return to a partially used plank later on*. Try to prove it does (or does not) matter. Investigate *bin packing* & *cutting stock*.